# Can't verify contract on etherscan.io

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, etherscan, verify

guys. I have created simple [contract](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/984146cd5d8f50b2182603932dd822ea), migrated to testnet via truffle. It can be founded [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x411af9af52fd4088e3d8ed321fd5a9aa62422d81). But I can't verify it. I double check:
1. name of contract
2. version of compiler (ver. 0.4.11 in etherscan and in solc inside truffle)
3. optimization is enabled as in truffle they are enabled
4. we have no construtor arguments or imports

I try migrating several times with my friend. No success. Any suggestions or help?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by verifying it ? Being sure this is really the contract you deployed ?

Comment: @NikitaFuchs something like this: https://etherscan.io/verifyContract?a=0x26cf05a5829dd739d0c93be57d6aeea326ef8c0f

Comment: Etherscan is for the main net, if you migrated your contract to a testnet, etherscan won't be able to find it.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to successfully verify the [contract code you linked](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/984146cd5d8f50b2182603932dd822ea) in a new deployment.

Are you sure the parameters and source code you used were identical to those you used in the verification tool?

For reference, [here](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x1e23cecbae327f171bd1abd4f8a96a1f8d729a0d#code) is the verification of the new deployment of your contract.

#### EDIT:

It *might* be that you are having the same problem as [I am having now](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19437/etherscan-how-can-i-verify-a-contract-with-multiple-imports-deployed-with-truff). It seems like the remix and truffle compilations produce different bytecodes for some reason.

Comment: did you compile code in remix? Could you list parametrs, which you used during compiling and verification?

Comment: How do you deploy a contract that has multiple inheritances?

Comment: @AverinMaxim Months later and I think I am having the same problem you had. Edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Also, to answer your question, I compiled your code in remix before.

Answer (score 2):

I've met same problem with contract verification at etherscan.io. 
https://etherscan.io/verifyContract2 - helped in my case.

Thank you

Comment: Link is no longer active.

Comment: It is passed time, etherscan removed that page, at the moment only [this link works](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract)

Answer (score 1):

I created `truffle-plugin-verify` to automate Truffle contract verification on Etherscan.

---

1. Install the plugin with npm

```sh
npm install truffle-plugin-verify
```

2. Add the plugin to your `truffle.js` or `truffle-config.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
  /* ... rest of truffle-config */

  plugins: [
    'truffle-plugin-verify'
  ]
}
```

3. Generate an API Key on your Etherscan account (see the [Etherscan website](https://etherscan.io/apis))
4. Add your Etherscan API key to your truffle config

```js
module.exports = {
  /* ... rest of truffle-config */

  api_keys: {
    etherscan: 'MY_API_KEY'
  }
}
```

---

After migrating your `Deck` contract to Rinkeby, you are able to verify it on Etherscan by running:

```
truffle run verify Deck --network rinkeby
```

---

More information can be found on [the repository](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify) or in my article [Automatically verify Truffle smart contracts on Etherscan](https://kalis.me/check-events-solidity-smart-contract-test-truffle/).