# Etherscan: How can I verify a contract with multiple imports deployed with Truffle?

Tags: truffle, remix, solc, etherscan, verify

When I deploy a contract with Truffle that has an `import` statement, and try to verify it on [etherscan](https://kovan.etherscan.io/verifyContract), my understanding is that I need to paste in the contents of the imported file.

I get an error on etherscan that the bytecodes of the concatenated and deployed files are not the same. 
The strange thing is that if I deploy the contract (with imports) on [remix](http://remix.ethereum.org/#version=soljson-v0.4.11+commit.68ef5810.js) then the bytecode matches with the concatenated source file.

#### Example

[Here is a minimal example](https://gist.github.com/travs/769f8b64cbdda5b3fccf85daf972097c) of contracts that exhibit this behaviour.

`Combined.sol` is the concatenated file, and `Outer.sol` contains the contract that is deployed.

Here is what I am doing that gets an error:

1. Deploy `Outer.sol` with truffle
2. Go to deployed contract address on etherscan
3. Input the `Concatenated.sol` source code and hit verify

Error, bytecodes do not match.

#### More info

- Using compiler `0.4.11` in remix and truffle.
- Ubuntu 16.04.
- On Kovan, not that it should matter.
- [Deployed contract](https://kovan.etherscan.io/address/0x2e527c290b48c247c05ff7d486e04a8440568a8a)

Comment: For me verification of concatenated contracts used to work like a charm. Can you provide the address of the deployed minimal example on the Kovan network so I can investigate the case?

Comment: @JakubWojciechowski Updated answer with address of deployed contract

Comment: When verifying the code on Etherscan, have you tried both with and without optimizations enabled?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently etherscan does not support verification of multifile contracts. But there is [discussion on etherscan's reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/etherscan/comments/6m12ef/verify_contract_imports/) about this issue.

Concatenating files into one worked some time ago, but since version 0.4.7 Solidity [includes hash of contract's metadata at the end of compiled contract](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#contract-metadata). As this metadata contains file names and hashes, you may get the same bytecode after concatenating and compiling but this hash will be different.

I think motivation behind adding hash of this metadata to deployed contract is to make source verification automatic as each deployed contract contains swarm-link to sources, compiler version and compilation options.

Comment: So basically the verification feature is pretty much useless since solidity 0.4.7 ?

Answer (score 4):

I built a CLI that may help you, called [multisol](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol). You can install it via Homebrew if you're on Mac, or [download](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol/releases) one of the executables I provide if you're on Windows or Linux:

```sh
$ brew tap paulrberg/multisol
$ brew install multisol
```

Then you can use it like this:

```sh
$ multisol path/to/YourContract.sol
```

This will generate a folder named "multisol-yourcontract" that can be used to verify the source code on Etherscan for a deployed instance of `YourContract.sol`. Note that the type of verification is "Solidity (Multi-Part files)".

Answer (score 2):

I created `truffle-plugin-verify` to automate Truffle contract verification on Etherscan.

---

1. Install the plugin with npm

```sh
npm install truffle-plugin-verify
```

2. Add the plugin to your `truffle.js` or `truffle-config.js` file

```js
module.exports = {
  /* ... rest of truffle-config */

  plugins: [
    'truffle-plugin-verify'
  ]
}
```

3. Generate an API Key on your Etherscan account (see the [Etherscan website](https://etherscan.io/apis))
4. Add your Etherscan API key to your truffle config

```js
module.exports = {
  /* ... rest of truffle-config */

  api_keys: {
    etherscan: 'MY_API_KEY'
  }
}
```

---

After migrating your `Outer` contract to Kovan, you are able to verify it on Etherscan by running:

```
truffle run verify Outer --network kovan
```

---

More information can be found on [the repository](https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify) or in my article [Automatically verify Truffle smart contracts on Etherscan](https://kalis.me/check-events-solidity-smart-contract-test-truffle/).

Comment: I am trying to verify a contract which uses multiple contracts but it fails with the below error:

truffle run verify AdminImpl@0xCDa9A9e6990999adfebbf8cADa2a6Ed2664d70A8 --network kovan
Verifying AdminImpl@0xCDa9A9e6990999adfebbf8cADa2a6Ed2664d70A8
Fail - Unable to verify
Failed to verify 1 contract(s): AdminImpl@0xCDa9A9e6990999adfebbf8cADa2a6Ed2664d70A8

Code to be verified: https://github.com/dydxprotocol/solo/blob/master/contracts/protocol/impl/AdminImpl.sol

I followed exactly what you have suggested and still trying to figure what is missing.

Comment: By any chance, was the contract deployed through another contract?

Comment: No, it is deployed independently. After having deployed, it is used in this contract: https://github.com/dydxprotocol/solo/blob/master/contracts/protocol/SoloMargin.sol

Comment: Could you open an issue on GitHub (with the output from running the command with the `--debug` flag? https://github.com/rkalis/truffle-plugin-verify/issues/new