# How do I verify a contract that has imports on etherscan?

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment, dapps, etherscan

There is an answer from 2017 [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19437/etherscan-how-can-i-verify-a-contract-with-multiple-imports-deployed-with-truff) saying that it's not possible but it's been 3 years since then so hopefully there is progress.

My Vyper contract looks something like this:

```
import ERC20 as ERC20
import SomeOtherContract as SomeOtherContract
```

How can I verify a contract that has imported other contracts on etherscan?

Comment: You replace those imports with their actual contents.

Comment: The answer in the link i posted said that's not possible because the solidity compiler appends a hash of the contract's metadata (which contains filename info etc.) to the end of bytecode - assuming the vyper compiler does something similar. But ill try it anyway..

Comment: Etherscan ignores the metadata.